# Any explanation why multiple linear layers work better than a single linear layer in practice?

Tags: neural-networks

It is a well-known math fact that composition of linear/affine transformations is still linear/affine. For a naive example,

$\textbf{A}_1\textbf{A}_2\textbf{x}$ is simply $\textbf{A}\textbf{x}$ where $\textbf{A}=\textbf{A}_1\textbf{A}_2$

Any one knows why in practice multiple linear layers tend to work better, even though it is mathematically equivalent to a single linear layer? Any reference is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure those "multiple linear layers" don't have nonlinear activations between them?

Comment: can you post a link to a source that explains the result you mention. There is some confusion as to whether or not you mean that a linear network performs better than its "mathematically reduced" network or if you misunderstand network activations. So a link to a source would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The key is that the layers of neurons in neural networks are *not* affine transformations. All commonly used neurons have some kind of non-linearity. The simplest of these is the Rectified Linear Unit (ReLU), which takes the form $y = x$ when $x > 0$ and $y = 0$ for all other values, where $x$ is a weighted sum of the inputs to the neuron.

Comment: I'm wondering if he read somewhere that linear networks perform better than the reduced architecture. Perhaps someone did an experiment with a linear network and its reduced equivalent and discovered that in practice the network performs better than the reduced form. I asked  OP to clarify.

Comment: @respectful Maybe. I think a lot of modern presentations show a linear algebraic presentation of neutral networks, and that for a new reader, it can be easy to miss the activation functions and their roles.